# iPod energy saving

Tags: ipod-touch, battery

I wonder if there is a difference in battery consumption between these two cases :

- I shut down the iPod with no app on.
- I shut down the iPod with an app on.

Is the app really paused, or is it still consuming power while "hibernate" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be close to the same; when you “suspend” your iPhone/Pod/Pad, all applications are suspended and only minimal services remain on (like Push, music player helper in case you press play from a headphone control, alarms if you have calendar, etc.).

But 3rd party applications are stopped, unless they have a service using the multitask API. But say you have X-Plane running and you suddenly turn the device off (suspending it). The app is automatically saved to “memory” and the process is stopped. No *additional* battery should be used until the iPod is powered up again.